# How do I build my project in eclipse? (from within the text editor)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I know that Ctrl+B "does the job", but it does not work from within the text editor. For instance, if I edit a .c file and press Ctrl+B, the project is not rebuilt. Is there a way to get this to work?

Also, are there keyboard shortcuts to jump through the compilation errors and show me the exact line where the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I have only just an advice. Check the Windows/Preferences/General/Key what and how bindings for CTRL+B (you can find it rapidly if you type '`ctrl+b`' the field top of the grid)